# How to make integration test fail when objectMapper throws exception

Tags: java, junit, jackson, junit5

I am writing using JUNIT 5 `junit-platform-console-standalone` library to write integration tests. While reading a JSON object with Jackson, I wish to fail the test if there is any error in reading file.

Tried adding throws IOException to method signature but that doesn;t seem to work.

```
@Test
void objectMapperTest(){
  // reading file line by line

  objname.foreach(obj -> {
    try{
      Result result = objectMapper.readValue(line,Result.class);
    } catch(IOException e) {
      //How to make the test fail ?  
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`fail()`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#fail-java.lang.String-)

```java
@Test
void objectMapperTest(){
  // reading file line by line

  objname.foreach(obj -> {
    try{
      Result result = objectMapper.readValue(line,Result.class);
    } catch(IOException e) {
      Assertions.fail("Test failure message");
    }
  });
}
```